# fetch blocked by privacy-gateway

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I'm making a fetch GET request and keep on getting returned the error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/search/6%george%20street.json?key=MY_API_KEY&typeahead=true&limit=10&language=en-GB&countrySet=GB&minFuzzyLevel=1&maxFuzzyLevel=2 fetch blocked by privacy-gateway`

Does this mean my fetch is being blocked by CORS?

It's obviously being blocked by something, but I thought if it was CORS, I'd get a corse error.

I noticed this fetch works on my own website, which is simple.

But if I make this fetch on my company website, I get the `blocked by privacy gateway` error.  Just wasn't sure exactly what `privacy-gateway` meant exactly?

Comment: Your browser can't verify the SSL certificate of the site you're trying to reach, it won't load the website because it suspects it is unsafe, you can try a few things,  see if the site's SSL certificate is expired / Clear the browser cache and cookies / Open the page in Incognito mode / Check the computer's date and time / Disable antivirus software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your browser suspect that the site you are trying to reach is unsafe since it can't verify the SSL certificate. There are a few things you can do if the problem comes from your computer:

1. Check if site's SSL certificate is expired.
2. Check the computer's date and time. Your browser compares the expiration date of an SSL certificate to the time on your computer's clock.
3. Temporarily disable your antivirus software's SSL scanning feature. It might be blocking sites not secured with SSL.
4. Clear the browser cache and cookies.
5. You can go for disabling the SSL certificate. This won't solve your issue; the problem will still be there, this will only help you to put the warning in silent.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and feedback, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the API end point was being blocked on the website I am working on.  And the team had to basically "whitelist" this API end point/domain.